# Where are campgrounds located within Kopaonik National Park, Serbia?

Tags: camping, serbia, national-parks

I'm probably going to hitchhike from Niš, Serbia to Kopaonik National Park.

I've done some searching and it seems [I can camp there and that there are no fees](http://www.summitpost.org/kopaonik/153988#chapter_7), but I cannot find any specific points within the park where the camping facilities are located.

Since the park is big and I'll be hitchhiking it could be quite important to know which spots on the map to aim for so I don't get stuck in the wrong part far from any campsite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I can say after research that there is no such thing there as [areas for camping](http://www.kopaonik.net/eng/_html/yellowpages.html) - you can set your tent anythere in safe, and relax.

But be aware to the [rules of National park](http://www.npkopaonik.com/O-Nama/Pravilnik-o-unutrasnjem-redu.html). There are general things there, but I suggest you to check this on arrival. During summer in Kopaonik some hiking tours are available from various firms, and, maybe, you could find any information about camping there.

Comment: Ah I couldn't tell if there might be places with either other campers, facilities like toilet blocks and fireplaces, or minimal security. Thanks.

Comment: @hippietrail As I've understood from rules and news, they tried to create some area for campers. But can't say for sure.

Comment: Setting up a tent anywhere is generally allowed in Serbia, but seems not to be within Kopaonik NP. Maybe it's ok to do right outside of NP boundary.

Comment: @dbkk: Oh that's interesting. Did you not notice my question on the topic of [free camping in the Balkan countries](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/where-in-the-balkans-is-free-camping-permitted)? It would be cool if you could contribute an answer to that one.

Answer (score 5):

According to a few Serbian websites, camping (setting up a tent) is not allowed in Kopaonik NP. A few Serbian campers mentioned setting up a tent a bit far off the road in the woods (being aware it's disallowed).

Further search found [this inn/restaurant](http://www.381info.com/brus/restorani/restoran-promaja) which includes camping grounds. It is located in Vlajkovac, 244th km of the road from Belgrade (that would be the road to the north -- red line on [the map](http://www.brzece-viladjurdja.s5.com/images/karta.jpg)).

*Note:* no personal experience with camping in Kopaonik, so don't take this as a recommendation.