# Is it possible to camp in a tent in Finland

Tags: camping, finland

In the beginning of October I want to make a little bicycle trip in Finland.

Is it possible to stay with a tent in Finland?
Or maybe available some areas where you can make a camp for free?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/where-is-wild-camping-possible-in-europe and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/what-exactly-is-allemansr%C3%A4tten-in-sweden

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Certainly, there are lots of [campsites in Finland](http://www.eurocampings.co.uk/finland/).

Even better, Finland has the concept of '[jokamiehenoikeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam#Finland)' or freedom to roam, and :

> "One may stay or set up camp temporarily in the countryside, a
>   reasonable distance from homes, pick mineral samples, wild berries,
>   mushrooms and flowers (as long as they are not protected species)."

What you might need to consider, however, is the temperature in October, depending on where you are.  Up north in Rovaniemi, for example [some might  find it quite chilly to be camping or cycling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rovaniemi#Climate).

Comment: All Nordic countries have basically the same thing, as described by the linked Wikipedia article (Denmark's seems to be somewhat more restrictive, though). It's called "allemansrätt" in Swedish and "allemannsrett" in Norwegian (literally, "every man's right"), and basically grants the right to stay temporarily or pass through most places as long as your presence does not cause an inconvenience to the land owner. This comes down in part to the culture in the Nordic countries being very similar, from back when the national borders looked quite different from what they do today.