# Wild Camping in Poland

Tags: europe, camping, poland, eastern-europe

Any suggestions for wild camping in Poland?

1. Nice views (Prefer mountains, not hills)
2. Would love to have a river close by
3. Ability to have camp fire - MUST HAVE.
4. Not too many people around

Any suggestion in welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

As [Where is wild camping possible in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/where-is-wild-camping-possible-in-europe/5463#5463) mentions

> in Poland [...] any camp fire away from designated areas is illegal

so any wild camping will, at best, be tolerated.

Comment: Any recommendation for the specific region?

Comment: illegal <> enforced