# Is it legal to wild camp (with a car) in Ireland?

Tags: driving, camping, ireland

I'm planning a road trip around Ireland later this year. My route plan is completely joined up and booked apart from one night where I can't get somewhere to stay. Is there anything to stop me (laws or local customs) stopping me from parking up and either pitching a tent somewhere quiet at the side of the road, or sleeping the back of my car? It's an estate with plenty of space for a sleeping bag with the seats down, not curled up in the passenger seat!

In England and Wales pitching a tent outside of a specified campsite is frowned upon but sleeping in a car you can usually get away with if you're away from main roads/angry farmers - is Ireland any different?

Comment: Parking a car at the side of the road is not really 'wild camping'.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't think of a better tag! ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is wild camping possible in Europe?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/where-is-wild-camping-possible-in-europe)

Comment: The suggested duplicate only partially answers the tent part of this question but not the car one, therefore I suggest to leave this question open.

Comment: I don't think closing this as a duplicate of a very broad question, with somewhat inconsistent answers is a good idea. Especially as by the side of the road and "wild camping" are not necessarily synonymous.

Comment: The UK mainland statement in the question is not entirely true. It is correct as regards to England and Wales, but in Scotland, there is a right to roam and wild camping is permitted, with some restrictions.

Comment: @CMaster But motorised vehicles are specifically excluded from the 'right to roam' in Scotland. There's plenty of places in Scotland that prohibit overnight parking.

Comment: Where did you look for accomodations? There is usually plenty of B&Bs that are not on reservation websites. Some don't have their own website. However, you can just look for signs or try to find phone numbers on the village / county websites. Where do you plan to stay? I can point you to relevant websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camping wild is illegal but tolerated, as in Wales & England ([here](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/1995/act/10/enacted/en/html?q=Occupiers%20Act), [here](http://irishbackwoods.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/wild-camping-in-ireland.html) and [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100602102101AAQnaHO)).
Sleeping in your car is legal ([here](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g186605-i90-k2464488-Sleeping_in_a_car_in_Irland-Dublin_County_Dublin.html)).